# Why do we addAll(Collection) but not Iterable?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

You can add a collection to list either supplying it as argument to `constructor(collection)` or `.addAll(Collection)` method. But, `Iterator/Iterable` would suffice that. If designers wanted to follow the [fundamental principle: be liberal in what you send and be conservative in what you accept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), they should have accept the `List` or, even better, the `ArrayList`, so than nobody could ever find that method useful. So, why did they prefer to stop somewhere in the middle?

There is [a similar question "why is there Collection.list for enumerator but not for Iterable/Iterator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831837) and a [highly reputable person answers that this is for historical reasons, which can be worked around through .addAll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831900/1083704). But, I do not understand which `addAll` is he/she talking about. 
Here, I ask exactly because I see that `addAll` does not work with Iterable/Iterator.

Comment: You've inverted the meaning of that principle in your rephrasing.

Comment: You've got the principle completely backwards: be **liberal** in what you accept, and **conservative** in what you produce.

Comment: It seems that Collections designers inverted it first. Expert Dukeling says that the network principles do not apply here anyway. Do they?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

History: `addAll()` was added in Java 1.2, `Iterable` came with Java 5.

The people doing the SDK now had these options:

1. Replace the existing API (possible breaking a lot of code) or
2. Add a second `addAll(Iterable)` possibly breaking a lot of code.
3. Do nothing, which doesn't break any code but annoys a lot of people.

Since "don't break existing code" has a higher priority than "make people happy", that's what they did.

Comment: How does adding a addAll(Iterable) break anything. They added a stream() method in java8 and nothing broke. Sure they couldn't have added it before default methods, but in java8 they could totally have addded the overload.

Comment: @RedCrafterLP I answered this in 2013, Java 8 came in 2014. My guess would be to keep the API small. My gut feeling is that 95% of calls are `add()`, so `addAll()` isn't used that often. Now adding a specialization for a rarely used API doesn't make much sense unless it solves an important problem which it doesn't. Also, the API would consume the iterable which isn't obvious from the call -> would be another API which isn't as simple as it looks.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface wasn't added until Java 5 (1.5), with the introduction of the enhanced `for` loop. `addAll` goes back to the introduction of the Collections API in 1.2.

It seems like it would have made sense to have an `addAll(Iterator i)` method; I don't know why the designers chose not to. Guava is happy to accept `Iterator`s.

Comment: But `Iterator` has existed since 1.2.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel your point?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Iterator != Iterable

Comment: @MarkRotteveel True, and I might have permitted `Iterator`, but there's the downside that someone might create and advance one before passing it in, leading to an incomplete add. No idea if that's the rationale behind the choice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Iterator suffices. Why not to require ArrayList?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Iterator can always be incomplete. Why do we ever use it?

Comment: @MattBall The question itself mentions _"But, `Iterator/Iterable` would suffice that"_ so just answering for `Iterable` is not sufficient

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Why not sufficient? Itarator is even narrower than Iterable. If you have an Iterable you always have and Iterator. Do you apply inverted robustness principle? Might be we need to addAll(ArrayList) instead of Collection?

Comment: AFAIK, Iterator was intended to be used in a loop.  Why would you do `addAll(collections.iterator())` when you can do `addAll(collection)`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Because there's no inherent reason for an `Iterator` to be backed by a `Collection`. A number of languages (Ruby and Haskell in particular) tend to use the equivalent type for generators (such as numeric ranges).

Comment: @chrylis Java is not a functional language.  It is designed to prefer using loops. (See Java 8 for more functional support)

Comment: @PeterLawrey So's Ruby; as far as I understand the Java 8 functional features are built on top of the existing imperative codebase. Being imperative doesn't preclude the nice syntactic sugar of being able to have a `Range` class that `implements Iterable`.

Comment: @chrylis It doesn't prevent a lot of things like Guava doing such things.  The question is; should it be part of the core JDK? In the past this was no, in Java 8+ maybe.  Java tends not to add loads of sugar.  Some people like it, but the Java designers didn't.

Answer (score 2):

When `addAll` was added to `Collection`, there was no `Iterable` interface, so it couldn't be added at the time.  It could have been added later, but rather fill up the Iterface, and implementations with similar functions, it was not included.

BTW All `Iterable` in the JDK are Collections. 
AFAIK `Iterable` was added to support the for-each loop.

You could have had in Java 1.2

```
public void addAll(Collection);
public void addAll(Iterator);
public void removeAll(Collection);
public void removeAll(Iterator);
public void retainAll(Collection);
public void retainAll(Iterator);
```

But you would have

- Added methods which alter their arguments. addAll(Collection) does not alter the collection.
- Doubled the number of methods which do similar things which would have been confusing. E.g. they dropped unsigned primitives to minimise the number options for similar constructs
- Manipulating Iterators was not consider natural then (See Streams in Java 8)
- You wouldn't want xxxAll(Iterator) alone as this would have complicated the common case.

Comment: The Javadoc gives that explicitly as the reason for its introduction.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html says that it is opposite: all collections are Iterable. It does not say that Iterables are collections. OOP programming enforces the difference between "TypeA is TypeB" and "TypeB is TypeA". With the confusion you created it is easy to think that API designers made a right choice.

Comment: @Val Java 6 wasn't the first version.

Comment: Good trolling. Are you saying that we use Java 1? Otherwise, I am lost completely.

Comment: @Val A key premise of your question is that Java was designed as it is today which this is not the case. If you designed the language from scratch now, you would do a lot of things differently.  To understand how Java is now, you need to understand its history and you won't always get that from a Javadoc.

Comment: I understand the historical reasons. I just could not understand what you mean by remarking that `all iterables are collections`. This makes no sense to me. I see that you put things upside down and I do not see how history can change the fact that we have now.

Comment: @Val In the JDK, all the Iterables are Collections.  You could create an Iterable which is not a Collection, but the reality is, this is a rare use case. Just like you can have a subclass of Throwable which is not an Exception nor an Error, but I suspect it is something which doesn't occur to most people to even do.

Answer (score 2):

Mutable containers in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) have the method `addAllIterable(Iterable)`.

```
MutableList<Integer> list = FastList.newListWith(1, 2, 3);
Iterable<Integer> iterable = FastList.newListWith(4, 5, 6);
list.addAllIterable(iterable);
Assert.assertEquals(FastList.newListWith(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), list);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.